# Using the physical serial port on a BSFrance LoRa32u4?

Tags: serial, atmega32u4

I can use the serial-over-USB channel by simply using `Serial` in my code.

The LoRa32u4 has an RXD1 and TXD1 pair on pins 20/21 (Arduino 0/1).

[image]
https://docs.bsfrance.fr/documentation/11296_LORA32U4/LoRa32u4_pinout_diagram.pdf

How do I configure and use this serial port (for receiving NMEA GPS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [[ATmega32U4-based boards use] Serial1 to communicate via TTL (5V) serial on pins 0 (RX) and 1 (TX). Serial is reserved for USB CDC communication. For more information, refer to the Leonardo getting started page and hardware page.](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/)